# What's wrong with this Rust macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to write a macro that generates a `From` impl for an enum by wrapping the type in a certain variant.

I've come up with this:

```
macro_rules! variant_derive_from {
    ($enum:ty:$variant:ident($from:ty)) => {
        impl From<$from> for $enum {
            fn from(thing: $from) -> $enum { return $enum::$variant(thing) }
        }
    };
}
```

However, whenever I try to actually use this macro I get the following error:

```
error: expected expression, found `B`
|             fn from(thing: $from) -> $enum { $enum::$variant(thing) }
|                                               ^^^^
```

I couldn't figure out why this might be happening, so I ran a build with macro tracing on, and the macro apparently expands to the following (dummy types, of course):

```
impl From < A > for B { fn from ( thing : A ) -> B { B :: AVariant ( thing ) } }
```

When pasting this directly into the code, it compiles successfully. What gives??

[Here's a full example of the error.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a09ab8614625d2982996c857362f3c83&version=nightly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ty` placeholder only works as type, not as a namespace. Using `ident` instead should work just fine in your example.

`ident` doesn't accept `path`s ("`foo::Bar`") though (and using `path` also doesn't seem to work in this case); you should be able to workaround it by manually constructing paths like matching this: `$enum:ident $(:: $enum_path:ident)*` (use it like this: `$enum $(:: $enum_path)*`).

Comment: Won't this cause an issue if the enum is either generic or not directly `use`d by the current file?

Comment: You're right; I thought about it too and just edited my answer :)

Comment: Ah, and i suppose it's possible to construct generics support similarly.

Comment: Hm... generics can but lifetimes cannot. Whatever, that seems like a really edge case scenario so I'll ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `<_>::` to disambiguate that you want to use `$enum` as a type:

```
<$enum>::$variant(thing)
```

The macro works perfectly after that change ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74cdf17de3befe28d2dd1b195673edff)).